# Retreive data from psql in node.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, psql

I'm trying to test my psql DB. I'm using node.js for displaying dato into an HTML page. I've got retrivied data and displayed into the terminal but really I don't know what is the right procedure to do same into an HTML page.

Can someone show me the way?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some codes.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`psql` is not a "DB", it [is a terminal-based front-end to PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html). If you decided to use it to generate an HTML page, the best approach would be running it with html format:

```
t=# \pset format h
Output format is html.
t=# \o /tmp/so14.html
t=# select * from so14;
t=# \o
```

The above will generate such content:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th align="center">i</th>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="right">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="right">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="right">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>(3 rows)<br />
</p>
```